# Using jqxWidgets with esbuild

Tags: compiler-errors, esbuild, jqwidget, angular16

Since my **Angular** project takes too much time to compile, I wanted to build with **ESBUILD** So, added this to my **angular.json** file

`"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser-esbuild"`

But this is throwing an error,

```
jqxcheckbox.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: jqxBaseFramework is not defined
at jqxcheckbox.js:8:14939
```

Does this have anything to do with compatibility issue between jqxWidgets and esbuild? How to solve this?

> PS. I am using **Angular 16.0.3** and **jqwidgets-ng: ^16.0.2**